Initialize a non upgradeable smart contract in upgradeable smart contract
I am stuck in the issue where i need to initialize the FunctionsClient smart contract.
But since my smart contract is an upgradeable smart contract, I do not have the constructor function rather the initialize function so how will the FunctionsClient be initialized in this case.
Example Provided -
constructor() FunctionsClient(router) ConfirmedOwner(msg.sender) {}

Issue -
function initialize(address _admin) FunctionsClient(router) public initializer {
        _grantRole(ADMIN_ROLE, _admin);
        _grantRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, _admin);
}



initialize() is just a normal function call.

initializer modifier is called just once

You cannot call FunctionsClient(router) from initialiser - if the parent contract has initialisation logic you cannot call otherwise, you usually need to copy-paste this logic to the initializer



Hope you are doing well.
In short, in upgradeable smart contracts, you need to extend the Initializable contract and use the initialize function, because there is no constructor

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
